# RecyclerView data not showing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My ReycyclerView is not showing data, but once i removed `.setHasFixedSize(true)`, then only it will display. However, this causes another problem. On the first time entering the fragment, it works fine, my actionBar is displaying, but on the second time, it somehow overlaps or pushes away my ActionBar.

I guess `.sethasFixedSize` is necessary but if i keep it, it will not display data. What causes this?

**First time entering:**

[image]

**Second time entering (before `notifyItemInserted()`):**
[image]

**After notifyItemInserted():**

[image]

**fragment.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cartItemRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment.kt:**

```
onCreateView() {
    binding.cartItemRv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    binding.cartItemRv.setHasFixedSize(true) 
    cartAdapter = CartAdapter(productNameList, productVariationList, cartItemList)
    binding.cartItemRv.adapter = cartAdapter

    //code for retrieving data from Firebase
    cartAdapter.notifyItemInserted(productNameList.size-1)
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
class CartAdapter(...: RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CartViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.cart_item, parent, false)
        return CartViewHolder(itemView, mListener)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CartViewHolder, position: Int) {
        ...
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return productNameList.size
    }

    inner class CartViewHolder(itemView: View, listener: onItemClickListener) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: As Android Team suggests, try to avoid using RelativeLayout. Use ConstraintLayout instead. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Comment: @gioravered owh okay, i thought RelativeLayout is better, ok will change it

Comment: Show code of adapter

Comment: @cmak added, others i think is irrelevant

Comment: But where are you using `sethasFixedSize()`?

Comment: @cmak in `fragment.kt`, 3rd line

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the item xml

Answer (score 0):

about sethasFixedSize , if the size of  your the RecyclerView depends on the adapter's content you have to set the sethasFixedSize vlaue :  false
otherwise set it true .

// for depending on adapter
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);

// for doesn't  depend on adapter
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

Comment: tried both, my action bar still hides

Answer (score 0):

add NestedScrollView on the parent of RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cartItemRv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then set RecyclerView

```
cartItemRv.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

Comment: no luck, still doesn't work